# I am trying to find a formula that can highlight a cell in one column if it contains any of the words located in another column

Tags: excel

Column A contains US Cities, one city per cell, going down the column.

Column B contains sentences that may or may not contain one of the cities mentioned in Column A.

I would like to have Column B highlighted if it contains any of the cities mentioned in column A.

Note: There will be other text besides the city name in the cells.

Here is a sample of what it would look like without anything highlighted

[image]

Everything in column B should be highlighted except "from xyz"

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using Conditional Formatting. In Excel 2007 and later:

1. Select cells `B1:B4` by clicking on cell `B1` and dragging down to `B4`, so that `B1` is the [Active Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2680.jpg)
2. Click **Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule...**
3. In the **New Formatting Rule** dialog, select the **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** option
4. In the **Format values where this formula is true** textbox, enter the following: `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$4, B1))) > 0`
5. Click the **Format...** button
6. In the **Format Cells** dialog, set your desired formatting options (e.g. select the yellow color on the "Fill" tab), and click the `OK` button
7. In the **New Formatting Rule** dialog, click the **OK** button

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using VBA/Macros. For your example, press `Alt+F11`,  then insert module and put this macro code:

```
Sub highlight()
Dim n As Integer, strng As String
Dim LastRow As Long
    Columns("B:B").Select
    n = 1
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For n = 1 To LastRow
        strng = "=$A$" & n
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=strng, _
            TextOperator:=xlContains
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13551615
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Next n
End Sub
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1ZGw1WmVjSk5YNUE) is an example file you can check.

Comment: Just don't forget to enable macros after opening my example file.